# javascript/json nested for and for/in loops in framework7 popups

Tags: javascript, json, html-framework-7

Hi all I hope someone can help Im a bit stuck single developer on own , with the below what im trying to do is nest for loops, I have data back at the var  = I; but not at the next two for statements, when the popup is called only the last record comes back I can see in console the data is there and the ids for the link and the data within do illicitate around , however only the last record appears I haven't uploaded the json because its a really long script any help on this would be very appreciated I have been playing with nested loops and got them to work just not in the bellow I normally use for/in apparently that's bad practice from what ive read up so changed to flat for loops.

```
<pre>     $.getJSON('myurl', function (data) {
          console.log(data);

          var data = data.sponsor;
          var output = "";
          var myApp = new Framework7();
          var $$ = Dom7;
          output += "<ul>";

           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                  output += "<li class='list-block media-list sponsors list-block-search '>";                     
                  output += "<div class='item-media-auto'>" + data[i].images + "</div>"; //working
                  output += "<div class='item-inner'>";
                  output += "<div class='item-title-row'>";
                  output += " <div id='name' class='item-title'>" + data[i].title + data[i].id +"</div>";
                  output += "</div>";
                  output += "<a href=" + data[i].custom['panaone_sponsorurl'] + " target='_blank'>";
                  output +=  data[i].custom['panaone_sponsorurl'];
                  output += "</a>";
                  output += ' <p><a href="#" class="create-popup' + data[i].id +'">Create Popup</a></p>';
                  output += "</li>";

                 document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
                 output += "</ul>";  

             }

                 for (var l = 0; l < data.length; l++) {
                    $$('.create-popup'+ data[l].id).on('click', function () {

                 for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

                           var popupHTML = '<div class="popup '+ data[j].id + '">'+
                                   '<div class="content-block ">'+
                                     '<p>Popup created dynamically.'+ data[j].id + '</p>'+

                                     '<p><a href="#" class="close-popup">Close me</a></p>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                 '</div>'+

                 myApp.popup(popupHTML);
             }
        });  
    }
  });
 }                
    </pre>
```